# Joomla content cahcing issue

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, k2

I have a strange issue with Joomla content caching, the articles themselves take up to 10 mins to refresh their titles, images, text.

i have disabled System - Page Cache

Note i am also using cloud flare

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, cloud flare has some serious problems with caching. Check with them and they may send you some lines that you have to throw in your .htaccess to disable their caching.

Answer (score 0):

If you have specifically enabled page rules in CloudFlare to cache static content, then it's possible this is CloudFlare related, It's easy enough to check by deleting any page rules which could cause this.

I have dozens of Joomla sites using CloudFlare and I've never seen that there was a problem combining them, or that ClouldFlare would try and cache articles by default.

As you will know, by default CloudFlare will cache static content like javascript and CSS files, but from what you describe, it's seems unlikely that this could be a cause.

I know you mention that articles are being cached, but if you have double checked that
 - Extensions > Plugins > System - Page Cache is disabled
 - You have cleared System > Page Cache
 - You don't have any other caching enabled on your site
 - You haven't specified  custom `ExpiresByType` or `mod_headers` settings  in .htaccess

then try setting System > Global Configuration > System > Cache to Off and on the same window if you have selected memcache(d) for the cache handling, change it to File.

These last settings under System > Cache should only affect module caching, not article caching but it doesn't hurt to rule it out.

Good luck!

Comment: I just find out that Varnish installed on the server, that might be the problem !!!!!

Comment: good to know @sevoug, Varnish could certainly be factor. If you haven't seen it, there's at lleast one extension in the JED that you could try: http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/cluster-varnish-for-joomla